# How to recover ASIX AX88179 from backports installation

Tags: kernel, ethernet, interface, backport

I recently installed  `https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13.2/backports-3.13.2-1.tar.gz` with `make defconfig-wifi && make && sudo make install` ("successfully") and uninstalled it with `sudo make uninstall` because it removed my built-in WLAN interface as well.

Before this I installed driver from ASIX AX88179 (version 1.9.0) with `make && sudo make install && sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` which worked multiple times before (both installation and usage of the adapter).

When I install the ASIX driver again (both version 1.9.0 and 1.10.0 from from http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112&PLine=71) with the commands mentioned above the interface is listed in output of `lsusb`, but `sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.4.102` (which worked before) returns `SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`.

I'm using `Linux richter-lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 3.13.11-03131102-generic #201405081435 SMP Thu May 8 18:36:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (installed from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.2-trusty/ [1]).

`/var/log/syslog` says

```
[    8.549220] rts5139: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    8.549540] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_write_cmd
[    8.549544] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_write_cmd (err -22)
[    8.549576] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_write_cmd_async
[    8.549578] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_write_cmd_async (err -22)
[    8.549611] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_skb_return
[    8.549613] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_skb_return (err -22)
[    8.549619] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_read_cmd
[    8.549621] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_read_cmd (err -22)
[    8.549625] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_write_cmd_nopm
[    8.549627] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_write_cmd_nopm (err -22)
[    8.549650] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_read_cmd_nopm
[    8.549658] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_read_cmd_nopm (err -22)
[    8.549786] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_get_endpoints
[    8.549788] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_get_endpoints (err -22)
[    8.549827] ax88179_178a: disagrees about version of symbol usbnet_defer_kevent
[    8.549828] ax88179_178a: Unknown symbol usbnet_defer_kevent (err -22)
[    8.552744] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
```

What could that mean and how do I get around this to a working interface?

---

[1] Using this version is necessary because of system freeze with the default Ubuntu image, investigating and solving this issues makes sense, of course, but I'd be glad if I can keep this workaround for instance